# Inquiry about the Wolfram MathWorld entry on Odd Perfect Number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

I just have a quick inquiry about the [Wolfram MathWorld entry on Odd Perfect Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OddPerfectNumber.html).

Last sentence of the fifth paragraph states that:

> Hagis (1980) showed that odd perfect numbers must have at least eight distinct prime factors, in which case, the number is divisible by 15 (Voight 2003).

Since [Nielsen (2015)](https://math.byu.edu/~pace/BestBound_web.pdf) has already proved that odd perfect numbers must have at least ten distinct prime factors, does this mean that they must be divisible by $15$?

Upon inspecting [Voight's paper](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/articles/opn-mass-rev-060211.pdf), I was under the impression that the divisibility-by-5 condition only holds for odd perfect numbers with *exactly* eight distinct prime factors.

Can anybody confirm if my impression is correct?

*References*

Hagis, P. Jr. "An Outline of a Proof that Every Odd Perfect Number has at Least Eight Prime Factors." Math. Comput. 34, 1027-1032, 1980.

Voight, J. "On the Nonexistence of Odd Perfect Numbers." MASS Selecta. Providence, RI: Amer. Math. Soc., pp. 293-300, 2003.

Nielsen, P. P. "Odd perfect numbers, Diophantine equations, and upper bounds", Math. Comp. 84, 2549-2567, 2015.

Comment: No, the above statement just means when we have EXACTLY $8$ prime factors, then, the number must be divisble by $15$. (This is at least how I would interprete it). Note : I did not read the whole question before posting this comment, I made this interpretation independent from the statement you mentioned about the exactly $8$ factors.

Comment: @Peter:  Kindly flesh out your last comment into an actual answer, so that this question does not go unanswered, and so that I would be able to accept it.  Thank you very much!  =)